# how to remove blank items from ArrayList.Without removing index wise

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class ArrayListTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
        al.add("");
        al.add("name");
        al.add("");
        al.add("");
        al.add(4, "asd");
        System.out.println(al);
    }
}
```

o/p    [, name, , , asd]
desire O/p  [name,asd]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use [`removeAll(Collection<?> c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) :

> Removes all of this collection's elements that are also contained in
>   the specified collection

```
al.removeAll(Arrays.asList(null,""));
```

This will remove all elements that are `null` or equals to `""` in your `List`.

Output :

```
[name, asd]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove an object by value.

```
while(al.remove(""));
```

Comment: yes, but it will remove only first blank space,how to use remove("") method so all blank value from ArrayList will removed?

Comment: Use a while loop. When there was something to remove, `true` is returned. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the list, read each value, compare it to an empty string `""` and if it is that, remove it:

```
Iterator it = al.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    //pick up the value
    String value= (String)it.next();

    //if it's empty string
    if ("".equals(value)) {
        //call remove on the iterator, it will indeed remove it
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Another option is to call List's `remove()` method while there are empty strings in the list:

```
while(list.contains("")) {
    list.remove("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
................... 

for(Iterator<String> it = al.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    String elem = it.next();
    if ("".equals(elem)) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

I do not comment this code. You should study from it yourself. Please pay attention on *all* details.