# Remove blanks from String-List

Tags: java, list

I have a `List<String>` that can contains blanks `("")`.

Is there a simple way to remove all blanks from list? I used this way to do so.

```
ListIterator<String> it = values.listIterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  if (it.next().equals("")) {
    it.remove();
  }
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: list entry is blank or the entry in the list contains blanks in between?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520693/in-java-remove-empty-elements-from-a-list-of-strings

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 added an elegant [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method:

```
values.removeIf(String::isEmpty);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on [how to remove blank items from ArrayList.Without removing index wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131987/how-to-remove-blank-items-from-arraylist-without-removing-index-wise)

```
removeAll(Collection<?> c)
```

That works fine!

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in `List<C>` Interface named as `removeAll(Collections <?> c)` which able to remove all elements.

it will remove all your blank String from the list

```
 values.removeAll(Arrays.asList("")); //remove all blank String
```